# NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint breaking when using :setFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I'm having some issues when programatically adding a custom view to an existing view controller (created using NIB). Specifically, when that view controller appears I get the following error message for broken constraints:

```
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c4290a90 h=--& v=--& InfoToolbar:0x135e73d00.midY == 1002   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c4290ae0 h=--& v=--& InfoToolbar:0x135e73d00.height == 44   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c4290a90 h=--& v=--& InfoToolbar:0x135e73d00.midY == 1002   (active)>
```

The InfoToolbar is a view that is supposed to be at the bottom of the screen and it's frame is set with `[bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-44, screenWidth, 44)]`.

This code was written a long time ago and it seems the issue started when we upgraded to XCode 9. The error is strange because those constraints seems to work fine (ie. if the view was 44 tall, it's midpoint would be 21 above the bottom of the view which would be 1002 for an iPad Air in this case).

I've done some research on SO and I've tried setting setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on this view to false but when I do that the view disappears completely and I get `AUTOLAYOUT AMBIGUOUS` errors.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using constraints, why do you need `setFrame:`? Just set new constraints over your new `UIView` and call `setNeedsLayout`. I don't think that message has nothing to do with `setFrame:` anyway, looks like two constraints interfere with each other. Try to double check them. You usually only need two vertical and two horizontal constraints per view.

Comment: Yeah I know it's a bit odd but it's legacy code that I don't want to fix right now if I don't have to. I think it's related to `setFrame` because when `setFrame:` is called XCode will create the AutoLayout constraints at run time. That's why the conflicting constraints are `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`. However when I look at the log it seems like the constraints can coexist. The height *can* be 44 and the midY should be 1002. The logging only appeared after moving to XCode 9 so I'm wondering if that's the cause.